# Why ptrace attach succeeds but pidfd_getfd fails with permission error?

Tags: linux, docker

From reading man pages of both ptrace (`PTRACE_ATTACH`) and `pidfd_getfd`, both of them require `PTRACE_MODE_ATTACH_REALCREDS` check. But in my testing (on Ubuntu 20.4, kernel 5.15.0, and Docker 20.10.21) I can call ptrace attach inside a Docker container from parent process to a child process (both running as a root) without `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE`, but for `pidfd_getfd` I have to pass `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` when running a container, otherwise I get a permission error. Why is that?